# Move Bootstrap navbar measurement equal to its height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

The website I am developing using bootstrap has a header image followed by a bootstrap navbar. We like having a transparent navbar on the image but it looks weird when the navbar starts to stack on phones etc.

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/toemohm7/)

What I would like to do is the following

1. Move the navbar up by its own height so that the navbar is aligned with the bottom edge of the header image and on top of the header image.
2. Make the navbar have a background of 50% black with white text when on top of the image.
3. When the navbar wraps to more than one line I would like it to move back below the image and the background color to return to a solid color of `#808184`.

CSS

```
.navbar-engage {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=1, startColorStr="#E6FFFFFF", endColorStr="#E6FFFFFF");
 -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=1, startColorStr="#E6FFFFFF", endColorStr="#E6FFFFFF");
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="background-color:#FABC41; height: 50px;">BAR</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12" style="padding:0;"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://travelandwildlifephotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Camping-on-Fraser-Island1.jpg" alt="CLI Engage"> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-engage">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a> </div>
        <div>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: `when it wraps` isn't trivial. You would need to check element top positions if you are looking for a dynamic solution. Really not clear what you are asking or what you have tried with respect to using media queries - or if you are even familiar with media queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It seems that the navbar will, as long as it is only one line tall, be a constant height of 50px. If this is the case, then the fix to number one is as simple as adding

```
position:relative;
top:-50px;
```

to `.navbar-engage`. If this is not the case (the navbar can change height even if it is only one line tall - such as if the font size changes) then a bit of javascript will be needed get the job done.

2) To change the text color when the nav bar is all one line, we need a media query. The following will make the text white when the nav bar is a single line:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-engage a  {
        color:white;
    }
    .navbar-engage li a:hover {
        color:black;
    }
}
```

The second selector, `.navbar-engage li a:hover`, was added to make the text black on hover. This was not a part of your original request, but it greatly added to the readability of the content. Take it or leave it - up to you.

3) All we need to do is add another media query that will undo our positioning change and modify the background color of the nav bar:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-engage {
        top:0px;
        background:#808184;
    }
}
```

The final CSS will look like this:

```
.navbar-engage {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=1, startColorStr="#E6FFFFFF", endColorStr="#E6FFFFFF");
    -ms-filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(GradientType=1, startColorStr="#E6FFFFFF", endColorStr="#E6FFFFFF");
    border-color: #e7e7e7;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-engage a {
        color: white;
    }
    .navbar-engage li a:hover {
        color: black;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-engage {
        top: 0px;
        background: #808184;
    }
}
```

Please bear in mind, however, that in order to do this with CSS alone, some numbers had to be hard-coded in, meaning that changes to your markup could result in the css needing to be tweaked slightly to make things work.

I also have the working fiddle available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/PullJosh/o224pwpa/).

Comment: How come the text is blue in the stacked version even though I added the color: #FFFFFF;   code.

Comment: I see I had to add .navbar-engage a {
    color:white;

    }

Comment: The `color: white;` was only defined within the media query for large screens. On a small screen, that is removed, and the text reverts to the default link color. (Links tend to be pesky with their colors...)