# Bootstrap 3 Autosizing Inline Inputs with Small Column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to create an inline form within a small container (.col-sm-4).  Using a default inline form at this size automatically wraps into multiple lines, which I would like to avoid.  The look I am aiming for is here:
[image: Desired Layout]

At this point I have gotten the inputs to throw out their min-width and instead adhere to their bounding columns, but I cannot get the button in the spot I want it (and autosizing with the overarching container).

[JSFiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/16L3chdh/)

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 well">
    <div class="col-xs-7 form-col" id="input-dynamic">
        <input type="text"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 form-col" id="input-dynamic">
        <div class="input-group-addon">$</div>
        <input type="number"></input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1 form-col" id="input-dynamic">
        <button class="btn btn-danger">-</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#input-dynamic input[type=text] {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 28px;
}
#input-dynamic input[type=number] {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 28px;
}
#input-dynamic button {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 28px;
}
.form-col {
    padding-right: 2px;
    padding-left: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't run or produce the error you are mentioning.  Neither does the code you have posted.  can you update both please?

Comment: Didn't realize that the JSFiddle link didn't update to the lastest modification for whatever reason.  Forked and changed link.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/g8fra4u3/

Comment: @Dmitriy Thanks that's it!
[1] Why does Span act so much differently than Div?  I followed the examples on the Bootstrap site which uses Div.
[2] Do you know of a fix for why the '-' in the button is not centered?  It seemed to happen when I made the size so small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forked your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qf99gr65/).

I Implemented the inline-form techniques [discussed here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/?#forms-inline).

And built some of the elements using this [Bootstrap form builder](http://bootsnipp.com/j87klPolka/formbuilder3.html).  If you google Bootstrap form builder you will see many similar ones.

I also noticed you didn't add all the external resources to the JSFiddle so I did that as well.

If you have a really really small screen it gets scrunched but you could use a media query as discussed **[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458400/move-bootstrap-navbar-measurement-equal-to-its-height)** to change the layout for a small width.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <form class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6">
                            <input id="textinput" name="textinput" type="text" class="form-control input-md"></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6"><div class="input-group"> <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>

                                <input id="prependedtext" name="prependedtext" class="form-control" placeholder="Amount" type="text"> <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">-</button>
      </span>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I forked that and wrapped it in a size 4 div (of the overarching container) and am left with the same problem.  See JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/th9pbyz0/1/

Comment: Hit the nail on the head.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Kfriede**, Hi there. You said you want to **avoid** the form items from stacking.
Here is a **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9j2wc0y5/)** that will do that for the form.
But just because of the still having it to be used properly on a very small screen.
I added a media breakpoint at 320px to drop the button down below and expand the two inputs to take up 50% width each.
Hope this can help you get started here with this form.

```
<form class="row-fluid">

        <input type="text" class="input-style col-xxs-6 col-xs-4 " id="exampleInputName2" placeholder="Name">  
        <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Amount (in dollars)</label>

        <div class="col-xxs-6 col-xs-5 input-block">
            <div class="input-addon input-height col-xs-2">$</div>
            <input type="text" class="input-style col-xs-8" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="Amount">
        </div>

        <div class=" col-xxs-12 col-xs-3">  
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        </div>
</form>
```

[image: inline form]